# Monitor and restart long running PHP process (Ratchet) in development

Tags: php, node.js, ratchet, nodemon

I am playing with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (web sockets for PHP) for the first time, and having to stop and restart the process after every code change is getting annoying.

Is there a PHP equivalent to something like nodemon for nodejs? Something that will restart the process when files change, and show output to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) can be used for this. I originally thought it was only for Node, but it seems to support many different scripting languages including PHP. It can watch files for auto restart the server, and output is sent to a log file that can be `tail`-ed to see what's happening.

To start a PHP process with PM2:

```
pm2 start file.php
```

More documentation available [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#start-any-process-type)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would to use Grunt or Gulp with watchers.

- For grunt, you could use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) with [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to restart php.
- For gulp, you could use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) with [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to restart php.

Comment: I have limited experience with gulp. I assume this means using something like `gulp-shell` or `gulp-exec`? How will that work with the long running PHP process, because I don't just want to spawn a new process each time?

Comment: You can run any commands you want. Have it find the php process and kill it